# Computer doesn't acknowledge DNS response

Tags: dns

I have made my own local DNS server which responds to the usual sites, like [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), youtube, etc... No matter what IP I give, the computer tells me that the host couldn't be found.

**The query and the response:**

[image]

The answer looks fine to me, so I don't understand why it wouldn't work.

**The message I get about the domain:**

[image]

Just to be clear, no matter what IP I return the computer doesn't acknowledge the answer. Does someone have an idea for what could cause that?

Comment: This seems like Windows. How exactly did you create the DNS server, and how is the client defined?

Comment: For every question I know the answer for, I respond with the IP. The answer looks exactly like the real one. What do you mean by how the client is defined?

Comment: can you show us your DNS setup? for a DNS server set on my.own.domain you can't get an answer for google.com - either you need to tell your DNS server that it serves the google.com domain (this will break a lot if you need the real google.com domain) what you want to achieve can be done through the hosts file or you create each forward domain you want to replace, and harrymc asked you between other things for your `ipconfig /all` output which I suppose points to your DNS server, so you need is to configure your DNS server correctly. be aware that www.google.com ha a lot more than one (1) IP...

Comment: @Zina It isn't a real DNS server. When connecting to the network the DHCP sets the DNS server's IP to my IP (my PC's). I then listen to incoming DNS requests, if I already know the answer, I will send the address to the client. If I don't I plan to send the query to a real DNS server and send the answer back to the client.

Comment: what kind of DNS server is it?

Comment: It isn't a DNS server, it's my computer. My real default DNS server is my router, I switched it to my computer.

Comment: @Zink, It's like I am my own man in the middle.